# SQL using inner join

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports, inner-join

So this is the situation I have. I have 3 tables (`tblEmployeesinfo` , `sqlSumrepMTC`, `sqlSumrepMTC15th`) I display this info using inner join:

```
SELECT
       SQLSummRepMTC."RepCompany", SQLSummRepMTC."WHTax",
       SQLSummRepMTC."Company", SQLSummRepMTC."MonthName",
       SQLSummRepMTC."YearVal", SQLSummRepMTC."Basis",
       tblEmployeesInfo."LastName", tblEmployeesInfo."FirstName",
       tblEmployeesInfo."Company", tblEmployeesInfo."MInitial", 
       tblEmployeesInfo."Division", sqlSumrepMTC15th."WHTax",
       sqlSumrepMTC15th."Basis"
FROM
   {
     oj ("BIOMETRICS"."dbo"."SQLSummRepMTC" SQLSummRepMTC INNER JOIN
     "BIOMETRICS"."dbo"."tblEmployeesInfo" tblEmployeesInfo 
     ON SQLSummRepMTC."EmployeeNo" = tblEmployeesInfo."EmployeeNo")
     INNER JOIN "BIOMETRICS"."dbo"."sqlSumrepMTC15th" sqlSumrepMTC15th
     ON tblEmployeesInfo."EmployeeNo" = sqlSumrepMTC15th."EmployeeNo"
  }
  ORDER BY
      SQLSummRepMTC."Basis" ASC,
      tblEmployeesInfo."Company" ASC,
      tblEmployeesInfo."LastName" ASC
```

Let's say one employee has his record on `sqlSumrepMTC` with its field `Taxvalue` of 50 but he does not exist on `sqlSumrepMTC15th` my problem is that this record will not be displayed in the inner join since it does not have value on both tables. What i want to achieve is just display a 0 value when it does not exist in the other table. This is my report looks like.

```
    Employeeno      employeename   15th      30th
       01               james       10        20
       02                Chris      NULL      50
```

first record will appear in the report since it has both record existing in the two tables, the second will not since its null in the first table. I just need it to appear in the report if one value is null or is missing from the other. Thanks in advance

Comment: So then, don't you want an outer join instead of an inner join?

Comment: I think you should convert your INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I tried using LEFT JOIN and it still give me the same result. It just won't display the record if that particular `EmployeeNo` does not exist in the other table

Comment: Can you confirm the version of SQL you are using?

Comment: i am using MS SQL server 2005 and 2010

Answer (score 0):

You have two joins! Thus, if there is no record in `sqlSumrepMTC15th` you need to replace the second join with LEFT JOIN. If it is possible, that there is no join record in `sqlSumrepMTC15th` **AND** `tblEmployeesInfo`, you need to replace both joins with LEFT JOIN.

Furthermore, you can replace NULL by

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN attribute IS NULL
              THEN 0
              ELSE attribute 
         END AS resultColumName,
       nextAttribute
FROM ...
```